# Why doesn't this patch apply?

Tags: git

I'm trying to use `git add -p` to stage a specific hunk of changes to the index.

Here's the hunk as Git suggests:

```
@@ -7,8 +7,15 @@
     <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
   </head>
-  <body>
-    <div class="content container">
+
+  <body class="container">
+    <ul class="navigation">
+      {% if page.url != '/index.html' %}
+      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
+      {% endif %}
+    </ul>
+
+    <div class="content">
       {{ content }}
     </div> 
   </body>
```

and here is my attempted edit of that patch:

```
@@ -7,5 +7,5 @@                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     <title>{{ page.title }}</title>                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">                                                                                                                                                                                             
   </head>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
-  <body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
-    <div class="content container">                                                                                                                                                                                                           
+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
+  <body class="container">
```

Git rejects this patch, saying:

> Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]?

I don't get it though:

- Both `-` and `+` start at line 7
- Both `-` and `+` go on for 5 lines

When I look at the original file (below), and mentally attempt to apply my suggested patch, it seems to make sense. What's wrong?

For reference, here's the whole original file:

```
  1 <!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  2 <html lang="en">                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  3   <head>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  4     <meta charset="utf-8">                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  5     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">                                                                                                                                                                         
  6     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                                                                                                                                                                 
  7     <title>{{ page.title }}</title>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  8     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">                                                                                                                                                                                          
  9   </head>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 10   <body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 11     <div class="content container">                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 12       {{ content }}                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 13     </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 14   </body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 15 </html>
```

Also, here is a patch I wrote that Git doesn't complain about:

```
@@ -7,8 +7,9 @@
     <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
   </head>
-  <body>
-    <div class="content container">
+
+  <body class="container">
+    <div class="content">
       {{ content }}
     </div> 
   </body>
```

It's actually a better patch in some ways, but I'd like to understand why Git doesn't like my first approach.

Comment: Did you include the last three lines of the patch (for context) in your edited patch? I don't know if that matters, but it wouldn't be wrong to have it.

Comment: Yeah, my second patch attempt (the one that works) does have context at the end. The first one—the one in question—does not have context at the end. **I posted everything verbatim.** For a bit I thought context is mandatory, but I just ran into a Git-generated patch w/o end context. Then again, that patch was for a hunk at the of the the file. So, I don't know about context being required either.

Comment: try it with the context and report back.

Comment: That's pretty much my second approach, which works. Unfortunately I've already used this approach and am in the midst of applying some other patches, so I'd rather not go back :D

Comment: you didn't compare with minimal differences, so we can't really answer this question empirically. Hopefully someone who knows the rules for patches will answer based on those rules.

Comment: What do you mean by minimal differences?

Comment: if you want to find the thing that causes a problem, you change as few things as possible between tests so that you can easily identify what it is that lead to the problem. By changing both the presence of context and the number of + lines, we can't identify which of those two things allowed git patch to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is indeed required in patches, at least by default. By deleting the bottom context the patch is saying that the changes are the last lines of the file.

By looking in the `git help apply` manual at the -C (context) option it says "by default no context is ever ignored.". You can ignore context with `git apply -C0 my.patch`, but of course this doesn't help with the interactive edit you're doing as it's seemingly using the default.

Further reading of `git help add` I notice a section named "EDITING PATCHES" with the following paragraphs that finally says it all:

```
There are also several operations which should be avoided entirely,
as they will make the patch impossible to apply:

   ·   adding context (" ") or removal ("-") lines

   ·   deleting context or removal lines

   ·   modifying the contents of context or removal lines
```